# Using conditional if to retrieve a single document in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query the db such that if a field exists and is not null then that field is used to query the db else another field is used. Can't seem to find the appropriate way to do this. Will appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction please.

Thanks

```
 tester = await Test.findOne(
                { $cond: {
                    if: {mainId},---> check if not null 
                    then: {'mainId': data.mainId},
                    else: {'subId': data.subId} 
                 }});
```

Comment: Could you just use the or operator? Test.findOne({$or: [
   {'mainId': data.mainId},
   {'subId': data.subId} 
]}).

Comment: That actually works @anttud but I'm trying to ensure the mainId exists or is not null first. When using $or, In an event where it does not exist, it throws an error

Comment: But if this is actually OK for you @Hopez, I don't see any need to use this mainId, you can allways then search by your subId. Maybe I am wrong, but think about that also.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of 'and' and 'or' together.
You have will have two sub queries : 
1. And (exists and mainID matches)
2. (subID matches)
The two sub queries above will be ORed.

Mongo implicitly uses the '$and' operator, if you are using the operator on the same field. So, the query can be further simplified to:

```
Test.findOne({ 
    $or:[ 
        { 'mainId' :  { $exists : true, $eq: data.mainId }  }, 
        { 'subId' : data.subId  } 
    ] } );
```

$eq operator stands for equalto.